# error: positional initialization of field in ‘struct’ declared with ‘designated_init’ attribute [-Werror=designated-init]

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to adjust an old kernel module (written for 2.6.x kernel) for kernel 4.6.x.

The code has a struct declaration as seen below:

```
struct tcpsp_sysctl_table {
    struct ctl_table_header *sysctl_header;
    struct ctl_table tcpsp_vars[NET_TCPSP_LAST];
    struct ctl_table tcpsp_dir[2];
    struct ctl_table root_dir[2];
};
```

The struct initialisation is written as:

```
static struct tcpsp_sysctl_table tcpsp_table = {
        NULL,
        {{NET_TCPSP_TO_ES, "timeout_established",
        &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_ESTABLISHED],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_TO_SS, "timeout_synsent",
        &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_SYN_SENT],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_TO_SR, "timeout_synrecv",
        &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_SYN_RECV],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_TO_FW, "timeout_finwait",
        &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_FIN_WAIT],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_TO_TW, "timeout_timewait",
        &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_TIME_WAIT],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_TO_CL, "timeout_close",
        &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_CLOSE],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_TO_CW, "timeout_closewait",
        &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_CLOSE_WAIT],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_TO_LA, "timeout_lastack",
        &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_LAST_ACK],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_TO_LI, "timeout_listen",
        &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_LISTEN],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_TO_SA, "timeout_synack",
          &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_SYNACK],
          sizeof(int), 0644, NULL, &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {NET_TCPSP_DEBUG_LEVEL, "debug_level",
          &sysctl_tcpsp_debug_level, sizeof(int), 0644, NULL,
          &proc_dointvec},
         {0}},
        {{NET_TCPSP, "tcpsp", NULL, 0, 0555, tcpsp_table.tcpsp_vars},
         {0}},
        {{CTL_NET, "net", NULL, 0, 0555, tcpsp_table.tcpsp_dir},
         {0}}
    };
```

When I compile the modules, I get an error related to these lines of code:

> error: positional initialization of field in ‘struct’ declared with
>   ‘designated_init’ attribute [-Werror=designated-init]
>   {{NET_TCPSP_TO_ES, "timeout_established",

Is this related to a new C-style programming or is there any syntax problem. I cannot really understand what's going on.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why is the code using octal numbers?

Comment: @Lundin: That field is a UNIX file mode, which traditionally use octal (because they're logically made up of 3-bit fields).  You can see immediately that the permissions there are read/write for owner (the 6), and read-only for owning group and world (the 4s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `struct ctl_table` is now subject to randomized struct layout.  This means that initialisers for such structures must use *designated initialisers* - these are initialisers that explicitly name each field in the struct.  The fields within `struct ctl_table` have also changed since the kernel version that code was written for - the initial `ctl_name` member no longer exists.

You could update it like so:

```
static struct tcpsp_sysctl_table tcpsp_table = {
        NULL,
        {{/* NET_TCPSP_TO_ES */
          .procname = "timeout_established",
          .data = &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_ESTABLISHED],
          .maxlen = sizeof(int),
          .mode = 0644,
          .child = NULL,
          .proc_handler = &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
         {/* NET_TCPSP_TO_SS */
          .procname = "timeout_synsent",
          .data = &tcpsp_timeout_tbl.timeout[TCPSP_S_SYN_SENT],
          .maxlen = sizeof(int),
          .mode = 0644,
          .child = NULL,
          .proc_handler = &proc_dointvec_jiffies},
        /* ... */
```